# how are handles distributed after MPI_Comm_split?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

Say, i have 8 processes. When i do the following, the MPU_COMM_WORLD communicator will be splitted into two communicators. The processes with even ids will belong to one communicator and the processes with odd ids will belong to another communicator.

```
color=myid % 2;
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,myid,&NEW_COMM);
MPI_Comm_rank( NEW_COMM, &new_id);
```

My question is where is the handle for these two communicators. After the split the ids of processors which before were 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 will become 0 2 4 6 | 1 3 5 7.

Now, my question is: suppose I want to send and receive in a particular communicator, say the one hosting the even ids, then when i send a message from 0 to 2 using the wrong communicator the message could end up in the second communicator, is this correct? Thank you in advance for clarification!

```
if(new_id < 2){

    MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT,  2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM);
    MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, 2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         

}
else
{
    MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         
    MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2 , 0, NEW_COMM);


}
```

Full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];

{
    int myid, numprocs;
    int color,Zero_one,new_id,new_nodes;
    MPI_Comm NEW_COMM; 
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);


    int my_num, my_received;

       int old_id;


    switch(myid){

        case 0:
            my_num = 0;
            old_id = 0;

        break;


        case 1:
            my_num = 1;
            old_id = 1;

        break;

        case 2:
            my_num = 2;
            old_id = 2;

        break;

        case 3:
            my_num = 3;
            old_id = 3;

        break;

        case 4:
            my_num = 4;
            old_id = 4;

        break;

        case 5:
            my_num = 5;
            old_id = 5;

        break;

        case 6:
            my_num = 6;
            old_id = 6;

        break;

        case 7:
            my_num = 7;
            old_id = 7;

        break;


    }



    color=myid % 2;
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,myid,&NEW_COMM);
    MPI_Comm_rank( NEW_COMM, &new_id);
    MPI_Comm_rank( NEW_COMM, &new_nodes);



       //  0 1 2 3     4 5 6 7  //After splits we have these nums for 8 processors
       //  2 3 0 1     6 7 4 5  //After the below exchange we should have this...each two elements in each communicator will exchange to next two elements in that same communicator




        if(new_id < 2){

            MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT,  2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM);
            MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, 2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         

        }
        else
        {
            MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         
            MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2 , 0, NEW_COMM);


        }



    printf("old_id= %d received num= %d\n", old_id, my_received);


    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your question, making it clearer. Also, I fixed the ids related to the two new communicators created by the call to MPI_Comm_split.

First question. A single process after the call to MPI_Comm_split can get at most ONE handle to a newly created communicator (at most, indeed, the returned communicator may be equal to MPI_COMM_NULL for processes passing MPI_UNDEFINED as the value for the color parameter). This is the reason why beginners typically do not understand the semantics of this call: MPI_Comm_split is a collective call, and, as such, it must be called by all of the processes in the original communicator. So, every process calls it once, but the function returns $k$ communicators, depending on the values of the color parameter supplied by all of the processes, partitioning the processes into $k$ groups. If you are NOT comfortable with this powerful mechanism and want to create just one communicator, simply supply MPI_UNDEFINED as the value of the color parameter in every call made by a process which must not belong to the newly created communicator. But then, you should use other available functions that allow creation of a communicator, not MPI_Comm_split.

Second question. If the semantics is now clear, you will immediately recognize that a process using the communicator returned by MPI_Comm_split for point-to-point or for collective communications can NEVER exchange data with processes being part of another communicator returned by MPI_Comm_split. The communicators provide a different universe of communicators, since each communicator has associated a different group of processes.

Now, your code snippet will NOT work, even if called by processes belonging to the even ids communicator. Why ? Because the code executed when new_id < 2 will correctly send from process with rank 0 in the new communicator to the process with rank 2 in the new communicator, and the process with rank 0 in the new communicator will receive from process with rank 2 in the new communicator.
However, the else branch is flawed. Indeed, ALL of the processes with even rank >= 2 in the new communicator will execute it, not just the process with rank 2. In this case, this branch will be executed by processes with rank 2, 4 and 6 in the new even ids communicator. Of course, the processes with ranks 4 and 6 will hang forever, blocking respectively for a message never sent by processes 2 and 4.

Finally, since the same code will also be executed by processes with odd id in the other newly created communicator, the process with rank 1 will try to send and receive from process 3, and in the else branch the processes with ranks 3, 5 and 7 will try to send and receive as well. In this case, processes 5 and 7 will hang forever, blocking respectively for a message never sent by processes 3 and 5.

The code is easily fixed if you want to exchange data between the processes with rank 0 and 2. Simply use the explicit ids 0 and 2 and rewrite the if as follows:

```
if(!new_id){
    MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT,  2, 0, NEW_COMM);
    MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, 2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}

if(new_id == 2){

    MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         
    MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, NEW_COMM);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! When i print old id and new id, its prints old_id = 0 new id = 0
old_id = 1 new id = 0
old_id = 2 new id = 1
old_id = 3 new id = 1
old_id = 4 new id = 2
old_id = 5 new id = 2
old_id = 6 new id = 3
old_id = 7 new id = 3


rather than the one you edited. So, here two processes have the same id for example id 0. In this scenario how can i distinguish processes when i do mpi_send where i need an id of the receiver. Does key parameter in mpi_comm_split have to do anything with distinguishing processes in such scenario?

Comment: You distinguish processes by their rank in the communicator you want to use, as always. The key parameter allows you to say to MPI that either you do not care about rank reordering, allowing MPI to freely choose the new ranks (done by passing the same value in all of the processes for the key parameter) or you explicitly pass a different value for the key parameter according to your own rank order. Therefore, if you calls MPI_Comm_split correctly you get two new communicators, but there are two possibilities.

Comment: 1) first comm with ranks 0,2,4,6 second comm with ranks 1,3,5,7 and 2) first comm with ranks 0,1,2,3 second comm with ranks 0,1,2,3. In the second case, you must simply act accordingly when sending/receiving data. For instance, the exchange between processes with rank 0 and 2 in the first case becomes in the second case an exchange between processes with rank 0 and 1 instead. To make sure you are using the correct process, simply check as follows: if(!old_id && !new_id) for proc with rank 0 in the old comm

Comment: and if(old_id == 2 && new_id == 1) for proc with rank 2 in the old comm.

Comment: please look at "edit starts here" section that i just added. It contains my full code. I have added the comments just before the exchange step which is the if block. The comments show what the exchange should be. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You edit has been rejected by several other people. Your code and your understanding is still wrong. Moreover, you MUST NOT assign the old and new ids as you did in your code. It's MPI that assign ranks to processes in a communicator. You must use it, not create it!

Comment: is it possible to chat with you? i will try to explain what i really expected from my code. I think we have a misunderstanding.

Comment: ok please look at my post where i have added my full code. Basically i am just using the rank. If you read the comments just before the exchange if block then i think it will make more sense what i am trying to do. Basically since the two communicators have same ids 0 1 2 3 the if block what it does is exchange the first two elements of each block with the next two elements of the same block. So, if the nums in the 8 processes are 0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 then after exchange they should be 2 3 0 1 | 6 7 4 5.