# Understanding MPI group communication

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to understand the concept of MPI group communication through the following example:

```
int new_rank, rank, size, ranks1[4]={0,1,2,3}, ranks2[4]={4,5,6,7};
MPI_Group Original_Group, New_Group;
MPI_Comm comm1;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Original_Group);

    if (rank < 4) {
      MPI_Group_incl(Original_Group, 4, ranks1, &New_Group);
      }
    else {
      MPI_Group_incl(Original_Group, 4, ranks2, &New_Group);
      }

MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, New_Group, &comm1);

MPI_Group_rank(New_Group, &new_rank);

printf("rank= %d newrank= %d \n",rank,new_rank);
```

In fact, I want to divide `n*n` matrix to a set of processors, say 9 processors, such that each row is divided into 3 blocks and sent to 3 processors in a group to perform some calculation. For example: The following figure shows `n*n` matrix is divided into `sqrt(n)` blocks and assigned to different processors such that each row forms one group, i.e. P1,P2,P3 is group 1, P4,P5,P6 is group 2 and so on.

|  P1 |  P2 |  P3 |

|  P4 |  P5 |  P6 |

|  P7 |  P8 |  P9 |

I tried to play with the previous code by creating 3 groups (each group for each row processors) but my program crashed. Does it mean I don't need to make 3 groups? If so, how P1, for example, knows its neighbor processors in its group?

Comment: In your example you could have used MPI_Comm_split which is simpler. There are several examples in the web (http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/). If you need specifically to use MPI_comm_group, please be more specific on how your code crashed, what error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use MPI_Comm_split, I don't see how groups are performed here.  Does it imply that each split corresponds to a group ?

Comment: Actually it is not a crash. It results frozen screen with no outputs

Comment: from the man page: ' A new communicator is created for each subgroup and returned in newcomm. ' look there for the full explanation: https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_split.3.php And I found an exhaustive answer about MPI_Comm_split in an older post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737842/how-are-handles-distributed-after-mpi-comm-split